# Remove if the next element is smaller

Tags: ruby, algorithm

Update:
On ruby I'm trying to remove next element if it is smaller than previous.

the input will be

```
a = [2,1,3,4,7,6,8]
```

so the output will be

```
a = [2,3,4,7,8]
```

obviously if none if all are sequential there will be no element removed.

Comment: Your question statement is wrong.  The numbers you removed are 1 and 6.  The elements after them are bigger, not smaller.

Comment: May be you want to remove _next_ element if it is smaller than previous?

Comment: yuri that's right let me updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
a.each_index.map { |i| a[i] if i < 1 || a[i-1] < a[i] }.compact
 => [2, 3, 4, 7, 8]
```

Comment: this one does the work, tnx Yuriy

Answer (score 2):

```
b = a.take(1) + a.each_cons(2).flat_map { |x, y| y >= x ? [y] : [] } 
#=> [2, 3, 4, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a.each_cons(2).reject{|x, y| x > y}.map(&:first) + [a.last]
# => [1, 3, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: it gives `[1, 3, 4, 6, 8]` for me. but he wanted `[2,3,4,7,8]`

Comment: @YuriyGolobokov It gives the same result for me as it did to you. Look at the output I wrote. The OP is contradictory.

Comment: oops. yes, the question doesn't match the example.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of what the previous value was, and use select to filter out the values that you don't want.

```
prev = - 1.0/0.0 #negative infinity
a.select {|num| delete = (prev < num); prev = num; delete}
```

On the input [2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 6, 8] this gives the output [2, 3, 4, 7, 8].

Comment: if you have an array like [1,2,3] it removes the first one

Comment: Huh, it's working fine for me. It doesn't seem like it should behave badly on [1, 2, 3], since -Infinity should be less than everything. Is this a Ruby version difference maybe? I'm on 2.0.0, what about you?

Comment: I'm on ruby 1.9 for some reason is removing the first one

Comment: Check to see if prev actually equals infinity at the beginning.

Comment: this is the output http://note.io/15du78e

Comment: I found it, its the pry console, maybe it doesn't like the infinity values http://note.io/15duTBY

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [2,1,3,4,7,6,8]

prev = a[0]
p a.chunk { |e|
  prev, prev2 = e, prev
  prev<prev2
}.flat_map{|i,j| j unless i }.compact
# >> [2, 3, 4, 7, 8]
```

**Update**

As @zetacu said:

> if you have an array like [1,2,3] it removes the first one

No it will not be stopped working.

```
a = [1,2,3]
prev = a[0]
p a.chunk { |e|
  prev, prev2 = e, prev
  prev<prev2
}.flat_map{|i,j| j unless i }.compact
# >> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: if you have an array like [1,2,3] it removes the first one

Comment: @zetacu no dear! Run the code,it is working as expected..

Comment: mm my bab maybe I type something extra in the console